# Adam's Apple and Voice box

Tags: human-biology, sexual-dimorphism

Why is Adam's Apple more prominent in males? Is it due to bigger voice box pushing the cartilage more, or is the cartilage indeed bigger than that in females? I am assuming bigger voice box as males have a "deeper" sound. Is it correct to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you nailed it!

Adam's apple (aka.  [laryngeal prominence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam%27s_apple)) exist in both men and women. It is a piece of bony cartilage called [thyroid cartilage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyroid_cartilage) that wraps around the [larynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larynx) (aka. voice box).

The Adam's apple is more prominent in males because males have have a bigger larynx (giving males a deeper voice). In males, the prominent Adam's apple typically appears during [adolescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolescence), when the larynx increases in size and the voice becomes deeper.

Comment: So the cartilage is prominent because the  voice box pushes it out, right?

Comment: It was maybe not clear before. The larynx is what people call voice box (I now clarified this point in my answer). Adam's apple is the cartilage that wraps around the larynx so if the larynx is big, the cartilage will be prominent.